# Is "Agree to NOUN" instead of "Agree to VERB" acceptable?

Tags: word-usage, confusable, phrasal-verbs

I'm aware about two usages of the verb *agree*:

*To agree **with** somebody or something*:

> I agreed *with* him.
>   I agree *with* this idea.

*To agree **to** do something*:

> We agreed *to* stop and eat.

However, I often notice the following usage <sub>*yes, I read these documents carefully*</sub>:

> [...You agree **to** the terms and conditions of this agreement](https://onlinefamily.norton.com/familysafety/termsconditions.fs)

Is this usage correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, verbs in collocation with a preposition often form a construction that has its own distinct or nuanced meaning.

**Agree with** - I *agreed with* him; I *agreed with* his decision; Also, the food *agreed with* me (the food was acceptable to my stomach).

**Agree to** - I *agreed to* the conditions; I *agreed to* go with him.

**Agree on** - We *agreed on* the time of the meeting.

**Agree about** - We *agreed about* the color; it was awful.

**Agree** - We *agreed*; we *agreed* that you should go; we *agreed* we would be there.

Comment: This is a nitpick, but in your second example for "agree to," "to" is not a preposition; it's part of an infinitive.

Answer (score 1):

This usage is absolutely correct. Please have a look in [multifaceted meanings of Agree](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/agree?q=agree).

> (agree to or to do something) say that one will do something which has been suggested by another person: she had agreed to go and see a movie with him

The "Terms and Conditions" are to be followed by you when you are using something. So you are **Agreeing *to*** follow them and abide by them. So the usage is undoubtedly correct.

Comment: I don't know what is missing verb, but it can be interpreted as _Implied verb_.

Comment: Just had a glance on [missing verb](http://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/sentence-fragments.html) and it seems it is not a **missing verb**, because it is not missing the _VERB_.

Comment: Actually, "follow* is missing, but yes, "implied" is a way better term.

Comment: "Follow" is neither missing nor implied - it's best to think of "consent to follow" as one of the meanings of "agree to".

Comment: @MarkBeadles "Consent" as a verb, you mean?

Comment: @bytebuster Correct, "to agree to" = "to consent to follow/abide by"